# I want to know all worker nodes' situation in WSO2 elastic load balance environment

Tags: wso2, application-server, elasticsearch

I have built a WSO2 elastic load balance environment (deploy pattern) based on [Worker/Manager clustering deployment pattern 2](https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=32346071)

Now I have 5 worker nodes and 1 mgt node. How or where can I see all worker nodes' situation in mgt node?

Comment: You can't see those information on Manager node. That's not the job of Manager node.

Comment: Manager node is there to handle the work with workers. Not to handle the worker's state.

Comment: OK, then, where can I, or what product should I install in order to , see  the information of worker nodes ? 

For example,  a worker node may crash or something wrong, how,  where, or in what WSO2 product can  I know it ?